# Deserialize JSON array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have developed service which returns JSON string.
Return string is as below:

```
string result = [{"ID":"1","ProductName":"Canon"},{"ID":"2","ProductName":"HP"}];
```

Now i want to deserialize above JSON string.

I have tried with below examples, but unable to do it. Getting error for all.

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(result);

string[][] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(result);

var serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string[] resultArray = serialize.Deserialize<string[]>(result);
```

can anyone please help me out?

Comment: try creating a class and declare it as [JsonObject], then setting [JsonProperty("ID") string ID {get;set;} and [JsonProperty("ProductName") string productname {get;set;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"[{""ID"":""1"",""ProductName"":""Canon""},{""ID"":""2"",""ProductName"":""HP""}]";
        IEnumerable<Product> result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Product>>(json);
    }   
}

class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = result.ToDictionary(product => product.ID, product => product.ProductName);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve what you want either create concrete `class` to store your values

```
public class MyJsonValueClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ID")]
    public int Productid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProductName ")] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<MyJsonValueClass> jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyJsonValueClass>>(json);
```

Otherwise use the `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` list of dictionary will get the data if you don't want to create the class for it.

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> dataFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

Comment: With approach the concrete class or `dictionary list` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to represent each element:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialize into `TestClass[]`.

You can then use .ToDictionary() if you need it in that format:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lookup = deserializedArray.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.ProductName);
```